# How do you trigger the on collapse event on a bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This question is most likely a repeat, but I can't seem to find the answer on any other related one. When the navbar collapses on smaller screens, how do you trigger an event signaling that the collapse button icon has been clicked? I have tried using the following js code below to no avail:

```
$('#main_nav').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        alert('collapse')
 })
```

Or this:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        console.log("collapse");
});
```

This is my code so far:

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="autohide navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" id='my-nav' >
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img src="" alt="logo" width="40" height="40" id="logo"/>
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main_nav">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" id="toggler"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-color" id="main_nav">
                    
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </nav>
```

Which class/id should I reference in the jquery event listener in order to invoke the event the happens when the collapse button is clicked on smaller screens?

Comment: Do you want to trigger the event? Or listen the event? I don't see the code that you are trying to trigger the event, but only listening the event. I couldn't reproduce from the HTML you provide. It doesn't show anything.

Comment: However, from the [Navbar document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/) they use collapse functional and from [collapse document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#events), they use 4 events. `show.bs.collapse`, `shown.bs.collapse`, `hide.bs.collapse`, `hidden.bs.collapse`. Please read carefully which even do you would like to listen (if you want to listen not trigger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to I'm a little confused that Original Poster asked about trigger the event but what he trying to do is listen the event (from the code).

So, I'll try to solve both.

The OP's HTML did not showing any contents in the navbar menu. I'll use an example from Bootstrap document instead.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main_nav" aria-controls="main_nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<p>
    Custom buttons
    <button id="trigger">
    collapse/expand.
    </button>
    <button id="triggerexpand">
    expand.
    </button>
    <button id="triggercollapse">
    collapse.
    </button>
</p>
```

```
$('#main_nav').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    console.log('on collapsing')
});
$('#main_nav').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    console.log('collapsed')
});


$('.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    console.log("on showing");
});
$('.navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    console.log("already shown");
});


$('#trigger').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('trigering');
    const event1 = new CustomEvent('hide.bs.collapse', { bubbles: true});
    const event2 = new CustomEvent('hidden.bs.collapse', { bubbles: true});

    let thisButton = e.target;
    // use dispatchEvent() (not working).
    $('#main_nav')[0].dispatchEvent(event1);// not working.
    $('#main_nav')[0].dispatchEvent(event2);// not working.
    // try to dispatch event on root document (not working).
    document.dispatchEvent(event1);// not working.
    document.dispatchEvent(event2);// not working.

    // use jQuery.trigger() (not working).
    $('#main_nav').trigger('hide.bx.collapse');// not working.
    $('#main_nav').trigger('hidden.bx.collapse');// not working.

    // do jQuery trigger "click". (collapse/expand WORK).
    $('.navbar-toggler').trigger('click');
});

$('#triggerexpand').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // trigger to expand only.
    let myCollapse = document.getElementById('main_nav');
    let bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
      toggle: false
    });
    bsCollapse.show();
});

$('#triggercollapse').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // trigger to collapse only.
    let myCollapse = document.getElementById('main_nav');
    let bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
      toggle: false
    });
    bsCollapse.hide();
});
```

In my code above, I listen all 4 events on navbar. You can use any selector (`#main_nav`, or `.navbar-collapse`).
The event listener you are using is already correct, in case that you want to listen the events and not working it is come from your incorrect HTML.

I added the trigger button to do trigger event as in your question. Please notice again that trigger event is NOT the same as listen event.
To trigger event, you can't just use `.dispatchEvent()` or `.trigger()` with event name. That is not working with Bootstrap collapse events.
To make trigger event works, you have to trigger click instead. Using `.trigger('click')` will tells jQuery to do click on that button and navbar will be collapse/expand, the events will be fired.

See it in [jsfiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/awhq8tkv/1/), [2](https://jsfiddle.net/brgz07Ln/).

Answer (score 1):

For the events in Bootstrap to work properly, be sure to enter jQuery and boostrap.js in the head.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then in the case of events, the event must be fired on the parent element with the .navbar class.

```
$('.navbar').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        console.log("collapse");
});
```

Also modify your html code to the form below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id='my-nav'>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
    <img src="" alt="logo"/>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main_nav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-color" id="main_nav">
    
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```